# "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure", but only from same server call

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, https, certificate

**TLDR:** Webservice call through https works from another computer but from local server (itself) it gives "System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException, System.Net.WebException The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure".

I have a  **website** (EDIT: the website itself in not on https, just on http. It is accessed via a dns name that is bound to a website through IIS bindings.) and a web**service**, both running on a **server** with **hostname** and  **ip-address**.
(I'm probably not allowed to disclose the actual names and addresses).
Corporate CA **CA** issued a  **certificate**, with the following properties (among others):

```
Issuer: CA
Subject: CN = hostname
Subject Alternative Name: IP Address =  ip-address
```

I deleted the http binding in IIS for webservice, leaving only the https.

| Type | Host Name | Port | IP Address | Binding Information |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| https |  | 443 | **ip address** |  |

**Website** calls **service** using url:
https://**ip-address**/**service**.asmx
and code:

```
using (WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse()) {
    do stuff...
}
```

the "GetResponse()" function throws several errors in a row:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
```

The exception message is:

```
The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

Inner exception:

```
The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

I have an exact copy of the **website** - **website_local**, that makes a call to the same **service**. That makes it a remote call (from my pc to the **server**). **And it works without exceptions.** There is no **http** binding anymore, so there is no way the connection is not secure.

If I go to "https://**ip-address**/**service**.asmx" with Chrome from both my pc and the **server** it says that the connection is secure and the certificate is valid and trusted (because of **CA** certificate being present in "Trusted Root")

What i did so far:

1. On a **server** put the **certificate** in both "LocalComputer\Personal" and "LocalComputer\Trusted Root Certification Authorities"
2. Put the **localhost** certificate into "LocalComputer\Trusted Root Certification Authorities"(it already is present in "Personal")
3. Ensured that **CA certificate** is in "LocalComputer\Trusted Root Certification Authorities"
4. For **certificate** in LocalComputer\Personal did: "All tasks -> Manage private keys -> Add -> IIS_IUSRS -> Full control and Read". (localhost certificate already had that setting).
5. Tried switching url from "https://**ip-address**/**service**.asmx" to "https://localhost/**service**.asmx" and "https://**hostname**/**service**.asmx" - not worked in code and Chrome (my pc and **server**) says, that the connection now is not secure and NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID.

**So the question is:**
Why the call from my **local website** works to the **service** (a remote call), but fails when the actual **website** makes a call to the same **service** (same server call)?

**UPD 1:** If I try to call the same service using Postman with SSL verification enabled, it says: "Unable to verify the first certificate".
Why does it works in code then?
I can request another certificate from company's CA, but I need specifications.
Can someone please elaborate on that? Current **certificate** has both **hostname** and **ip-address** and should be valid for any service on that website, shouldn't it?

Comment: Does your certificate also have 127.0.0.1 and ::1 addresses? because most likely when you're calling self over web underlying TCP stack just loops back after DNS resolution.

Comment: In general, it is a weird design to use HTTP to communicate to things running on the same box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how we finally did it:

1. Registered a dns-name inside corporate LAN;
2. Issued a new certificate for that specific name, *without binding it to a server's ip-address*;
3. Added the new dns-name as hostname in IIS and added a new certificate.
4. Changed the connection string to https://**dns-name**/**service**.asmx

And it works!

My best guess is that @zaitsman was right about why it didn't work from server itself, but worked from my pc.

> Does your certificate also have 127.0.0.1 and ::1 addresses? because most likely >when you're calling self over web underlying TCP stack just loops back after DNS >resolution.